# PhoneGap with JQuery Mobile Not Drawing Correctly

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am investigating a few problems with using JQuery Mobile and PhoneGap.

When I using the viewpoint meta tag like this,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
```

The first observation is that my app doesn't like being changed from portrait to landscape or vice versa. If I rotate my phone (Android) the PhoneGap app immediately exits.

Also when I have something like this,

```
<div id="index" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
            <li><a href="#sync">Sync</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sync" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
        <a data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>
        <h1>Sync</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is a list with a link to a second page there called sync. When I click on the link to the second page the whole page moves down a pixel when it is drawing the animation to move onto the second page?

The other thing I would observe is that the text seems very small on my device, which is 480 x 800 ~ 246 DPI

I would need to solve these issues before deciding to continue with PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile.

UPDATE:

I started developing my app from scratch and rotating it doesn't cause the app to exit any more. The other problems still exist though.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I have used phonegap with jQuery mobile and found no issues in orientation change.

Comment: Why do you recommend that? What difference will it make?